# making .sh script for installing VNC server on CentOS 4.1

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to make a .sh script file for VNC install in centos server 4.1.1. Which will automate my work for installing VNC server.i made this primary file & it works but i stuck at coding the allow installation Y/N, display configs and edit/commenting values inputs.

> wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/co308vee1im1pkb/vnc.sh
>   chmod -R 777 vnc.sh
>   ./vnc.sh

**But i need to implement those too :**

- after each install command, a 'Y' input.
- after command `"sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/vncservers"` a input

  `[VNCSERVERS="1:root"  VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1324x700"]`

and save & exit.

- after command:`nano .vnc/xstartup` a `#` comment in 28th line and save & exit.

How to do those? Any advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Heard of the command `yes`? It's a common Linux command that will just print a stream of "yes"'s until killed.

As for your second problem, just run:

```
echo VNCSERVERS="1:root" VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1324x700" >> /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
```

By the way, if you let us know which command is asking for user input, there is probably a nicer way of skipping the `y/N` prompt than using the `yes` command